# How to use setState for just one widget

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, admob

I have a Future which takes a value from my Cloud Firestore database and displays an icon in the body of my app. If the value in the database changes, the icon updates. I have been using setState to rebuild my widget tree and this works fine - the app reacts almost instantly to changes in my Cloud Firestore database. This is great! Code:

```
Future<void> takenSurvey2() async {
 final sn = await Firestore.instance
 .collection('Controller')
      .document('Current Survey')
      .get();
 surveyName2 = sn['cs'];
 final snapShot = await Firestore.instance
 .collection('$surveyName2' + '_entrants')
      .document(userid)
      .get();
 if (snapShot.exists) {
 takenSurvey = true;
  } else {
 takenSurvey = false;
  }
  setState(() {});
}
```

and the place where the icon is shown is coded like this (within a stack):

```
Positioned(
    right: 30,
    top: 20,
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future: takenSurvey2(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
 if (takenSurvey == false) {
 return Icon(
              Foundation.burst_new,
              size: 48,
              color: Color(0xff303841),
            );
          } else if (takenSurvey == true) {
 return Icon(
              Foundation.check,
              size: 48,
              color: Color(0xff303841),
            );
          } else
            return Container();
        })),
```

However, I've added in my AdMob adverts using the 'admob_flutter' package, and because setState seems to be constantly running, the advert cannot load - I just see a flashing box. If I remove setState from the code above, the adverts load, but the icons in my app do not update when the value in Cloud Firestore changes.

How do I either exclude my admob_flutter widget from setState, or just use setState (or something else) to only update my FutureBuilder widget? I would like to do so in a way which limits the number of calls on Cloud Firestore, but this is not essential.

Thanks!